# One user getting 401 error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

I'm working on a MVC4 project and each build gets deployed to Dev and than QA environment.  With each build, members of QA has not had issues accessing QA site.  After the last deployment one QA user is getting IE username\password credentials.  If this QA person cancels or puts her Windows username/password in this user gets a 401 error in IE.  In Chrome, it just gives her a 401 error without asking for credentials.

She is able to go to dev environment without any issues with the same build.  So the problem is just in QA environment.

No one else having this issue(About 5 or 6 people have tried.).

The site is using Windows Authentication and everything on the IIS server seems to be setup correct.  This QA user having the problem didn't have any issues before this last deployment either.

The server hosting is Windows Server 2008 R2 and using .NET 4.0 with MVC4.

I had the user delete all browser cache, made sure there is no proxy server setup and made sure "Enable Integrated Windows Authentication" is checked in IE.  If any of these were not correct it wouldn't work in the dev environment either.

Can anyone give me any ideas on the best way to troubleshoot this?

Thanks for everyone's time.

**Edit**

Used Fiddler to view request and response. Both are done using IE.  The machine that is working is handling WWW-Authenticate(2 401 and a 200, which is a Kerberos handshake.). However the browser that is not working is doesn't seem to be handling WWW-Authenticate, instead it's the asking the user for username/password instead of sending Authorization: Negotiate.

***Request on machine that works(Request 1)***

```
GET http://MyLocalSite/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: MyLocalSite
Pragma: no-cache
```

***Response on machine that works(Response 1)***

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 30 Sep 2013 18:51:54 GMT
Content-Length: 1293
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
```

***Request on machine that works(Request 2)***

```
GET http://MyLocalSite/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Authorization: Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAl4II4gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAbEdAAAADw==
Pragma: no-cache
Host: MyLocalSite
```

***Response on machine that works(Response 2)***

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAACAAAADgAOADgAAAAVgonioA9ayIkT2AEAAAAAAAAAAJ4AngBGAAAABgGxHQAAAA9HAEUATgBJAE4ARgBPAAIADgBHAEUATgBJAE4ARgBPAAEAFABRAEEAMgBXAEUAQgBJAE4AVAAyAAQAFgBnAGUAbgBpAG4AZgBvAC4AYwBvAG0AAwAsAFEAQQAyAFcARQBCAEkATgBUADIALgBnAGUAbgBpAG4AZgBvAC4AYwBvAG0ABQAWAGcAZQBuAGkAbgBmAG8ALgBjAG8AbQAHAAgAX7yrIQ6+zgEAAAAA
Date: Mon, 30 Sep 2013 18:51:54 GMT
Content-Length: 341
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
```

***Request on machine that works(Request 3)***

```
GET http://MyLocalSite/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: MyLocalSite
Pragma: no-cache
Authorization: Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAJYAAAAYABgArgAAAA4ADgBYAAAAFgAWAGYAAAAaABoAfAAAABAAEADGAAAAFYKI4gYBsR0AAAAPTTUv/iiYRszkcKP+vEpEUkcARQBOAEkATgBGAE8AbQBhAHMAdAByAGEAdQBjAGsAYQBzAEkAVABHADUAQwBCADMAMAA4ADMAQwBOADMAMIrf5ReM2DwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFpY6vMa57pcoU9CLc22TN/M9wIwMgReGfPTodq1BeQGd0THtjF1BAg==
```

***Response on machine that works(Response 3)***

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 30 Sep 2013 18:51:54 GMT
Content-Length: 15195
```

***Request on machine that doesn't work***

```
GET http://MyLocalSite/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: MyLocalSite
```

***Response on machine that doesn't work***

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 30 Sep 2013 17:50:27 GMT
Content-Length: 1293
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
```

**Edit 2**

On the QA testers box, when it gives the user username/password box I put my credentials in everything works.  I have sent this to our NOG department but as of right now they can't figure it out either.  So any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: I would use Fiddler to work out what the request looks like that is causing the 401 on the problem users machine.  Then I would use the ability in fiddler to export the request and replay it on your machine to verify it is something purely in that request that is causing the problems.  If that proves to be true, that something in the Request is causing the 401, I would find an invalid and a valid request and inspect the differences, manipulating the valid request to fail or the invalid request to pass.  That will get you more information on what is causing this.

Comment: I looked at fiddler and I posted the request and responses.

Comment: You could check the ie -> advanced -> Enable Integrated authentication, or add your site as a trusted site in security, and see if that gets you somewhere.

Comment: Integrated authentication is already set.  Like I said, this same site(Same build and I believe IIS is configured the same.) works in a dev environment for this user.  If it was a IE setting, I don't think it would work in either environment.